# Set the variables $a$ and $b$ to a random value from 0-9. How many different lines can $ax+by=0$ form?

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

I recently had a Math Olympiad test, and I memorized a question that I couldn't find an effective solution for.

> Set the variables $a$ and $b$ to a random value from 0-9. How many different lines can $ax+by=0$ form?

The way I tried in the test (which was very, very ineffective, and I didn't even have enough time to solve the question) was to list how many duplicates of a fraction there were, and then subtract the amounts from $10^2$.

This is obviously not a plausible solution, and I still don't know what the answer is.

NOTE: I don't remember the exact words that the question used. If you need me to clarify anything, please comment.

Comment: Does order matter or is $ax+by = 0$ necessarily the same as $bx + ay = 0$?

Comment: Nope. $ax+by=0$ is not necessarily the same as $bx+ay=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more elementary approach, we can write the pairs into a $10\times 10$ grid.
$$ \begin{array}{cccc}(0,0) & (1,0) & \ldots & (9,0) \\
(0,1) & (1,1) & \ldots & (9,1) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
(0,9) & (1,9) & \ldots & (9,9)\end{array} $$
As you said, the order matters, so we can concern ourselves with the diagonal and one half triangle.

From the diagonal we get $(1,1)$. From the lower triangle
$$ 
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
(0,1) & & & & & & & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,2)}& (1,2) & & & & & & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,3)}& (1,3) & (2,3) & & & & & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,4)}& (1,4) & \color{red}{(2,4)} & (3,4) & & & & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,5)}& (1,5) & (2,5) & (3,5) & (4,5) & & & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,6)}& (1,6) & \color{red}{(2,6)} & \color{red}{(3,6)} & \color{red}{(4,6)} & (5,6) & & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,7)}& (1,7) & (2,7) & (3,7) & (4,7) & (5,7) & (6,7) & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,8)}& (1,8)& \color{red}{(2,8)} & (3,8) & \color{red}{(4,8)} & (5,8) & \color{red}{(6,8)} & (7,8) & & & \\
\color{red}{(0,9)}& (1,9) & (2,9) & \color{red}{(3,9)} & (4,9) & (5,9) & \color{red}{(6,9)} & (7,9) & (8,9) & \end{array}
$$
we just eliminate duplicates. Suppose the number of remaining entries in the lower triangle is $N$. The final answer would be $2N+1$.

---

A note on $(0,0)$. The equality $0x+0y=0$ is true for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. So it does not represent a line.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). As a beginner, your answer helped a lot to understand the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, assume $a<b$ (we will double the number of solutions at the end).

Put $a=0$. We have only one line for this case ($y=0$).

Put $a=1$. We have $8$ lines for this case.

Put $a=2$. We have $4$ lines for this case (only counting those values of $b$ which doesn't share any common factor with $a$).

Repeat this for $a=3,4,5$.

Add the case $a=b$ which will have exactly one solution.

Comment: Why do we double the number of solutions when $a<b$?

Comment: It's a symmetrical argument

Comment: @Tyrcnex You just said in the comments that $ax+by=0$ is not necessarily the same as $bx+ay=0$. That's why I asked to double the number of solutions. It basically depends on your question. If your question doesn't ask you to double, you may delete that part.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Tyrcnex You are welcome once again :)

Comment: @SayanDutta Give the $a=0$ case some extra thought. Are these lines necessarily different?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Oh yes! It was a foolish mistake. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find unique lines of the form $ax+by=0$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers between $0$ and $9$.

I would simply count them -

i) When either $a$ or $b$ is zero : $ \ 2$ solutions

ii) when $a$ and $b$ are both non-zero

Start with $a = 1$ and that gives $9$ solutions $(1 \leq b \leq 9)$. Now note that $a \geq 2$ do not give *new* solutions if both $a, b$ have a common gcd other than $1$ (including $a, b$). So,

$a = 2, 4, 8$ will give $5$ more solutions each.
$a = 3, 9$ will give $6$ more solutions each.
$a = 5, 7$ will give $8$ more solutions each.
$a = 6$ will give $3$ more solutions.

That is total of $57$ different lines.